# Calling UpdateResource to replace a resource drops RT_STRING resources

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, resources

I am trying to update a resource in a DLL file. The DLL file in question contains an [`RT_VERSION` (16)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648009.aspx) resource, several [`RT_STRING` (6)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648009.aspx), and a number of resources of custom resource types. I am using the following method to replace a single resource:

```
bool ReplaceResource( LPCTSTR a_ResourceFile,
                      LPCTSTR a_ResourceType, LPCTSTR a_ResourceName,
                      LPCTSTR a_SourceFile )
{
    // Open DLL file for editing
    HANDLE hResFile = BeginUpdateResource( a_ResourceFile,
                                           FALSE );// Don't delete existing resources
    if ( hResFile == NULL )
        return false;

    // Read in new resource file
    HANDLE hSrcFile = CreateFile( a_SourceFile, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
                                  NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0x0, NULL );
    if ( hSrcFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
        EndUpdateResource( hResFile, TRUE );
        return false;
    }

    DWORD dwFileSizeLow = GetFileSize( hSrcFile, NULL );
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer( static_cast<size_t>( dwFileSizeLow ) );
    DWORD dwBytesRead = 0x0;
    if ( !ReadFile( hSrcFile, buffer.data(), static_cast<DWORD>( buffer.size() ),
                    &dwBytesRead, NULL ) ||
         ( dwBytesRead != static_cast<DWORD>( buffer.size() ) ) ) {
        CloseHandle( hSrcFile );
        EndUpdateResource( hResFile, TRUE );
        return false;
    }
    CloseHandle( hSrcFile );

    // Replace resource
    if ( !UpdateResource( hResFile, a_ResourceType, a_ResourceName,
                          MAKELANGID( LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL ),
                          buffer.data(), static_cast<DWORD>( buffer.size() ) ) ) {
        EndUpdateResource( hResFile, TRUE );
        return false;
    }

    EndUpdateResource( hResFile,
                       FALSE ); // Don't discard changes
    return true;
}
```

The expected result is that this method replaces a single resource and leaves all remaining resources unchanged. Using it with a specific DLL file, however, in addition to replacing one of the custom resources, it also drops all `RT_STRING` resources.

I am calling [BeginUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648030.aspx) with `bDeleteExistingResources` set to `FALSE`, [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049.aspx) uses the right `wLanguage` parameter (language neutral), and [EndUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648032.aspx) is called with an `fDiscard` parameter set to `FALSE`.

Why do the `RT_STRING` resources get lost, and how to prevent this?

Comment: What are the values of `a_ResourceType` and `a_ResourceName`?

Comment: @Jonathan: `_T("IMAGE")` and `MAKEINTRESOURCE(1018)`, respectively. Although it doesn't appear to make a difference, which resource I'm trying to replace.

Comment: FWIW I tried this here with your code and could not replicate your findings. String resources were unaffected in the DLL I tested with. So maybe it's something to do with the specific DLL. Perhaps it is "corrupt" in some way and so when the resources are re-written the strings get dropped?

Comment: @Jonathan: The modifications were done on a copy of `%SystemRoot%\Resources\Themes\Aero\aero.msstyles`. Available .mui-files were copied as well. Target OS: Windows 7. The effect could be reproduced on Windows 8/8.1 as well.